# Android Studio 3.3 - Enable Navigation not found

Tags: android, android-studio-3.3, android-navigation-editor

I am learning [Navigation Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/#1), on First Step they are saying that,

```
1. Click File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences on Mac)
2. Select the Experimental category in the left pane
3. Check Enable Navigation Editor
4. Restart Android Studio
```

[image]

BUT

In **Android Studio 3.3**, I have created New Project which I have created, I followed above steps but did't found **Enable Navigation Editor** checkbox.

[image]

Have anyone faced this types of issue? Any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Android Studio 3.3, navigation editor is not in experimental phase anymore. To work with navigation, you can **create a new directory in resources folder** by name navigation and in that you can create a **new navigation.xml file**.

More info can be found in the link below

[Android Studio 3.3 release notes](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/)

Answer (score 3):

I just found release notes about [Android Studio 3.3](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/)

In that they have announced about [Implement navigation with the Navigation Architecture Component.](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/navigation-implementing)

### Create a navigation graph

To add a navigation graph to your project, do the following:

- In the Project window, right-click on the res directory and select **New > Android Resource File**. The **New Resource File** dialog appears.
- Type a name in the File name field, such as **"nav_graph"**.
- Select **Navigation** from the Resource type drop-down list.
- Click **OK**. The following occurs:

  - A `navigation` resource directory is created within the res directory.
  - A `nav_graph.xml` file is created within the navigation directory.
  - The `nav_graph.xml` file opens in the Navigation Editor. This XML file contains your navigation graph.
- Click the Text tab to toggle to the XML text view. You should see an empty navigation graph, as shown in the following example:

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  </navigation>
  ```

  Click **Design** to return to the Navigation Editor.